# Click a button on webpage with VBA

Tags: vba

I'm a beginner in VBA. I'm trying to click a button "Refresh" on web page using VBA. But i cannot do that.

could you please support me. Thanks all

HTML

Refresh" type="submit">

Refresh

Answer (score 1):

try with below

```
'References
' 1) Microsoft Internet Controls
' 2) Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub test()
    Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Dim ie As Variant
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "" ' Your webpage goes here
        While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_LOADED
            DoEvents
        Wend
    For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByName("submit")
        oHTML_Element.Click
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**

```
For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByName("button")
    If oHTML_Element.className = "btn btn-primary" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Karthick, i'm trying your code but it still does do as my hope. thanks

Comment: Code HTML as below

Comment: Code HTML as below: <button class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="<i class='icon-white icon-refresh'></i> Refresh" type="submit">
<i class="icon-white icon-refresh"></i>
Refresh
</button>

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

You can use a CSS selector applied via `querySelector` method of `document`.

```
button[type=submit]
```

Reads as element(s) with `button` tag having attribute `type` with value `"submit"`. `querySelector` will retrieve the first match.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

```
ie.document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").click
```